# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userService')

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userService')
```

while trying to access a method of my class `UserService` in another class called `ServicecenterController`.

At first, i create an instance of the class `UserService` in the `ServicecenterController`

```
export class ServicecenterController {
    private userService: UserService

    constructor(...) {
        ...
        this.userService = new UserService()
        this.initRoutes()
    }
```

Then i try to access a method of `UserService` in the `ServicecenterController`

```
const userOrgs = this.userService.getUserOrgsByEmail(email)
```

After compiling, the TypeError will occur

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userService')
    at ...\src\controllers\servicecenter.controller.ts:81:35
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at ...\src\controllers\servicecenter.controller.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (...\src\controllers\servicecenter.controller.ts:4:12)
    at getCases (...\src\controllers\servicecenter.controller.ts:78:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at middleware (...\node_modules\express-validator\src\middlewares\check.js:16:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Any help is appreciated, i am relatively new to TypeScript/Node/Express

EDIT
For @Konrad 's request to show the call of that function:
The line

```
const userOrgs = this.userService.getUserOrgsByEmail(email)
```

gets called in the method `async getCases()`. This method again gets called in

```
private initRoutes(){
        this.router.get('/', this.validationService.validateRequest('getDevices'), this.getCases)
        this.router.get('/latest', this.validationService.validateRequest('getDevices'), this.getLatestCases)
        this.router.post('/create', this.createCase)
    }
```

which is called in the constructor of `ServicecenterController`

Comment: Try to remove this line in constructor this.userService = new UserService()

Comment: @RahulBeniwal the error still occurs.

Comment: You lost `this` reference. Show how you call the function with that line `const userOrgs = this.userService.getUserOrgsByEmail(email)`

Comment: @Konrad i have edited my post to show the lines you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use

```
this.router.get('/', this.validationService.validateRequest('getDevices'), this.getCases.bind(this))
```

or

```
this.router.get('/', this.validationService.validateRequest('getDevices'), () => this.getCases())
```

Comment: Both solutions work for me, thanks!
Does either of them have any advantages?

Comment: If `getCases` had any arguments, it would be easier to use the second one. Other than that there is no difference